# Golang + Postgres. Не подключается к базе

Tags: postgresql, golang

Использую **lib/pq** и **jmoiron/sqlx**.

```
package repository

import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "fmt"
)

type Config struct {
    Host string
    Port string
    Username string
    Password string
    DBName string
    SSLMode string
}

func NewPostgresDB(cfg Config) (*sqlx.DB, error) {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=%s", cfg.Host, cfg.Port, cfg.Username, cfg.DBName, cfg.Password, cfg.SSLMode))
    db, err := sqlx.Open("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s post=%s user=%s dbname=%s password=%s sslmode=%s", cfg.Host, cfg.Port, cfg.Username, cfg.DBName, cfg.Password, cfg.SSLMode))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return db, nil
}
```

go run выдает следующую ошибку:

host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres dbname=test1 password= **sslmode**=**disable**
2022/01/26 15:02:47 failed to initialize db: %spq: **SSL is not enabled on the server**
exit status 1

То есть **sslmode** у нас в строке подключения выключен, но ошибка выходите следующая, что **SSL** для **postgres** не включен.
Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена за счет добавления одинарных ковычек в строку:

```
db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%s user=%s dbname=%s password='%s' sslmode=%s", cfg.Host, cfg.Port, cfg.Username, cfg.DBName, cfg.Password, cfg.SSLMode))
```

Поле **password=** было нечитаемым видимо. Поэтому добавление кавычек **password=''** решило проблему.